# How to keep DbContext in Connected state with Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

Since Web APIs are stateless when you have EF Core backend after any request the DbContext would be disconnected.

Therefore we have made `QueryTracking` as `NoTracking` since default behavior `TrackAll` doesn't give any benefit since its a web application

```
DbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

Is there anyway to keep DbContext in connected state when using over a Web API?

E.g:

- Request 1: Customer information is retrieved from Web API
- Request 2: Customer information is saved through another endpoint.

Is there a way to reuse/keep in connected state for the above scenario?

Comment: If by 'connected state' you mean by: Keep the changes that were made in your model, throughout the execution of your webapi app, it doesn't make sense to me, besides, it would consume a huge amount of resources (depending on how long you would need to keep your app running).

Comment: I Agree but what is the use of the default TrackAll behavior then? It's only useful for Desktop applications but if the desktop client is used by many again the purpose is lost

Comment: Not exactly, it means that all the changes that are going to be made in your model >>during the request<< will be tracked. So for the whole request workflow, you can track or not the changes in your model, depending on what you wanna do... for reading operations for instance one might disable the 'trackAll' options.

Comment: But if you really want to keep your dbcontext aware of everything what is happening in your app you can put it in a static variable, it will last for the whole application (but no, you don't wanna do that).

Comment: I don't want to keep the state throughout the application. I want to keep db state for a particular user for a particular action. By action I mean first request to get data and second request to persist data.

Comment: Why would you need to keep the DbContext for a request to GET and to PERSIST data? I don't see a scenario where one could need that, do you mind clarifying it a little bit? Nevertheless, you could create an instance of the DBContext per User, and store it in a static/session, but again, I don't see any reason to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to understand a scenario where connected state can be used. I can't think of any but that is the default behavior of EF

Comment: @Nipuna Chris Pratt explains some of the misconceptions in this question. A DbContext is *always disconnected*. DbContexts are disposed as quickly as possible, whether you use them in a web or desktop application. Tracking has nothing to do with connections. The default TrackAll is *very useful* in web applications - how else would you load an entity based on an ID and modify one of its fields?

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be suffering under a number of misconceptions/misunderstandings. First, connections are entirely separate from tracking, state, and everything else here honestly. Particularly if you employ connection pooling, the same database connection may very well be used across many different requests and even context instances. Just because the context is disposed does not mean that the connection to the database is also closed. Likewise, instantiating a context doesn't always equate to a new connection being established.

Second, query tracking has to do with the object cache EF keeps and the change tracking it does. Turning this feature off can have some perf benefits as the cache and change tracking do consume some amount of resources. However, it can also negatively impact performance, depending on the type of queries you're doing. The object cache in particular can prevent subsequent queries from even needing to be issued, if the objects have already been retrieve via other means. But, importantly, the object cache is intimately tied to the context instance, and therefore has the same lifetime as the context itself. It does not persist across requests, which you seem to understand, but it *does* persist across operations done within a single request pipeline, which you seem to not understand. The context could potentially be utilized any number of times during a single request, so there is still value in the query tracking. Rather than turn it off completely, you should pick and choose on a case by case basis when to not employ it via adding `.AsNoTracking()` to the query, if it makes sense to do that in that particular circumstance.

Third, *HTTP* is stateless, not just Web APIs. Even traditional HTML returning web applications are stateless. Things like `Session` are fake state. Each HTTP request is completely unique, unconcerned and unaffected by anything that has happened before or since between the client and the server. In the case of sessions, auth, etc. an identifier is transferred to the client from the server (a cookie), and the client sends that back to the server with each subsequent request. That allows the illusion of state, but it's really being established anew each time.

As such, there is no way to persist the results of query between requests, save from using something like `Session` or a cache. Even then, the result for your purposes here would not work, as the data would have to be serialized/deserialized, removing any ties to any sort of state tracking, i.e. it's just data, and EF, for example, would know nothing about it or how to persist changes to it.